# AWS lambda rollback while publishing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-webapi, aws-serverless

i am a Lambda Learner using c# and visualstudio (aws toolkit)

when i try to publish a simple api(lambda application c# without test - webapi)
i am getting this below error

```
2020-12-05 00:31:08 UTC+0530    Lambdaapp2  ROLLBACK_COMPLETE   -
2020-12-05 00:31:07 UTC+0530    AspNetCoreFunctionRole  DELETE_COMPLETE -
2020-12-05 00:31:06 UTC+0530    Bucket  DELETE_COMPLETE -
2020-12-05 00:31:06 UTC+0530    AspNetCoreFunctionRole  DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2020-12-05 00:30:57 UTC+0530    Lambdaapp2  ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS    The following resource(s) failed to create: [AspNetCoreFunctionRole, Bucket]. Rollback requested by user.
2020-12-05 00:30:56 UTC+0530    AspNetCoreFunctionRole  CREATE_FAILED   Resource creation cancelled
2020-12-05 00:30:56 UTC+0530    Bucket  CREATE_FAILED   lamaws already exists
2020-12-05 00:30:56 UTC+0530    AspNetCoreFunctionRole  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated
2020-12-05 00:30:55 UTC+0530    AspNetCoreFunctionRole  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2020-12-05 00:30:55 UTC+0530    Bucket  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2020-12-05 00:30:52 UTC+0530    Lambdaapp2  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  User Initiated
2020-12-05 00:30:45 UTC+0530    Lambdaapp2  REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS  User Initiated
```

Comment: `lamaws` check this already exist either you remove this first and try.

Comment: thanks it got created. but lamaws is a existing bucket name .

Comment: didn't get this ?

Comment: instead of creating new bucket through publish dialog. i directly created in s3 and tried to use